# not able find location on iPhone device

Tags: iphone

I have added code for finding location, this is working on simulator but it is not working on iPhone device. I have enabled the location services but still it is not working.

```
-(void)firstTimeRefresh {

CLLocation *bestLocation = [[[AppDelegate getAppDelegate] locationManager] bestLocation];
if ( bestLocation != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Using Best Loaction");
    [self getArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bestLocation.coordinate.latitude], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat: bestLocation.coordinate.longitude], nil] :@"false":page_no];
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code and its working at mine end.

> ```
> locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
> [locationManager setDelegate:self];
> [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
> [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
> ```

Define the CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate in .h class file 
when location is updated this function will get called.

> ```
> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
> }
> ```

Comment: installing the app, did ask for accessing the location?

Comment: have you enabled the location services in iPhone settings?

Comment: everything is seems to be fine here, could you share some sample project for this?

Comment: hey,problem is in device.. it is not able to find the location.. now my code is working properly on another device.

Comment: I thought it as the last options that why I have asked about some sample piece of code.